# Geopandas shapefile axis not on same scale as actual picture

Tags: python, plot, geopandas

I'm following this tutorial, and everything looks the same
https://towardsdatascience.com/geopandas-101-plot-any-data-with-a-latitude-and-longitude-on-a-map-98e01944b972

That is I get the map to display, the dataframe looks the same format etc etc. However, the axis scale is weird, going to + 1M, which is causing all points to render right by the (0,0) coordinate. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It's supposed to be a normal long/lat axis

Here is the code I'm using for the streetmap:

```
street_map = gdp.read_file('/Users/mkjacks5/Documents/projects/Mobile data/data/geo/Maricopa_Street_Local_2013.shp')
```

And here is the code for the plot itself

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
```

street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color = "blue")
geo_df.plot(ax= ax, markersize = 50, color = "red", marker = "^", label = "Destination")
plt.legend(prop={'size':15})

I am encoding the long lat coordinates to points using

```
crs =   {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show output of `street_map.head()`? It seems to me that you have mixed CRS, that your `geo_df` is in long lat (degrees) but `street_map` in some projected CRS.

Comment: I thought this was handled by "crs =   {'init' :'epsg:4326'}". But here is the steet_map.head() output https://i.imgur.com/G0qUaWY.png. I see in the geometry column, those number looks to be of the scale the map is showing. Also looking at the documentation it def looks like it's something with the crs encoding, but I just can't get it to work. the output of street_map.crs is {'proj': 'tmerc',
 'lat_0': 31,
 'lon_0': -111.9166666666667,
 'k': 0.9999,
 'x_0': 213360,
 'y_0': 0,
 'ellps': 'GRS80',
 'units': 'ft',
 'no_defs': True}

Comment: I'd try `geo_df = geo_df.to_crs(street_map.crs)` once you define that gdf to have both geodataframes in the same projection.

Comment: Thanks, I had to work around it a bit but got it to work using

crs = from_string("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
street_map = street_map.to_crs(crs=crs)

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using

```
crs = from_string("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") 
street_map = street_map.to_crs(crs=crs)
```

Comment: where is this `from_string()` func coming from?

Comment: from fiona.crs import from_string